# ScrollView not scrolled with weights in it

Tags: java, android, scrollview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:measureAllChildren="true"
    android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

           contents like button textview are here

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

           contents like button textview are here


        </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</Scrollview>
```

While KeyBoard popup the scrollview is not scrolled as we think ...

Comment: So what *does* happen when the keyboard shows up? Can we get a screenshot or something?

Comment: I need to scroll the edittext after clicking edittext box